# How can I join two unrelated mysql table and use group by date

Tags: mysql, cross-join

I have 2 tables voucher and ledger the fields are
**Ledger:**

```
id  total_sale  cancel_amount  date
1    3000           0           2018-01-20
2    3000           0           2018-01-29
3    5000           0           2018-01-30
4    10000          500         2018-01-30
5    2000           100         2018-01-31
6    2000           0           2018-01-31
```

**voucher:**

```
id  expenditure    date
1    500          2018-01-20
2    800          2018-01-30
3    1000         2018-01-30
4    200          2018-01-31
5    300          2018-01-31
```

I want a result like[ date between 2018-01-29 to 2018-01-31]

```
date           total_sale   total_expenditure
2018-01-29       3000           0
2018-01-30       15000         1800
2018-01-31       4000          500
```

Please someone help

Comment: Union all and  conditionally aggregate

Answer (score 0):

For such requirements, always prefer a dimension table. Then you'll never get confused on joining two dissimilar tables witch no keys in common.

Tables:

```
create schema test;

create table date_dim(date date);
insert into date_dim values ('2018-01-20'),
('2018-01-21'),
('2018-01-22'),
('2018-01-23'),
('2018-01-24'),
('2018-01-25'),
('2018-01-26'),
('2018-01-27'),
('2018-01-28'),
('2018-01-29'),
('2018-01-30'),
('2018-01-31');

create table ledger(id int,total_sale int, cancel_amount int, date date);

insert into ledger values
(1,3000,0,'2018-01-20'),
(2,3000,0,'2018-01-29'),
(3,5000,0,'2018-01-30'),
(4,10000,500,'2018-01-30'),
(5,2000,100,'2018-01-31'),
(6,2000,0,'2018-01-31');

create table voucher(id int, expenditure int, date date);
insert into voucher values
(1,500,'2018-01-20'),
(2,800,'2018-01-30'),
(3,1000,'2018-01-30'),
(4,200,'2018-01-31'),
(5,300,'2018-01-31');
```

SQL Script (for solution):

```
 select l.date,total_sale,
total_expenditure
from 
(select d.date date,sum(total_sale)total_sale
 from ledger l right join date_dim d on l.date=d.date
 where d.date between '2018-01-29' and '2018-01-31'
group by 1)l

 join 
(select d.date date,sum(expenditure)total_expenditure
 from voucher v right join date_dim d on v.date=d.date
 where d.date between '2018-01-29' and '2018-01-31'
group by 1)v
on l.date=v.date
group by 1,2,3;
```

Resultset:

```
date       total_sale   total_expenditure
2018-01-29   3000        (null)
2018-01-30   15000        1800
2018-01-31   4000         500
```

Check the solution at [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/546a3e/3)

Answer (score 0):

You're hoping to present three different aggregates as columns of your result set.

1. distinct dates
2. net sales (total less canceled) (I **guess** that's what you want.)
3. expenditures.

You need to create three subqueries and join them.

The dates: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/666dcb/1/0)

```
          SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date) date FROM Ledger
           UNION 
          SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date) date FROM Voucher
```

The net sales: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/666dcb/2/0)

```
         SELECT DATE(date) date, 
                SUM(total_sale) - SUM(cancel_amount) total_sale
           FROM Ledger
          GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

The expenditures: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/666dcb/3/0)

```
         SELECT DATE(date) date, 
                SUM(expenditure) total_expenditures
           FROM Voucher
          GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

Then you need to join them together on date. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/666dcb/5/0)

```
SELECT d.date, s.total_sale, e.total_expenditures
  FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date) date FROM Ledger
           UNION 
          SELECT DISTINCT DATE(date) date FROM Voucher
       ) d
  LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT DATE(date) date, 
                SUM(total_sale) - SUM(cancel_amount) total_sale
           FROM Ledger
          GROUP BY DATE(date)
       ) s ON d.date = s.date
  LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT DATE(date) date, 
                SUM(expenditure) total_expenditures
           FROM Voucher
          GROUP BY DATE(date)
       ) e ON d.date = e.date
 WHERE d.date >= somedate AND d.date <= anotherdate
ORDER BY d.date
```

Why do the first subquery--the one with the dates? It makes sure you get a row in your final result set for dates that don't have any sales or any expenditures.

Why do separate subqueries?  Because you want to end up joining three virtual tables--three subqueries--that have either zero or one row per date. If you join tables with more than one row per date, you'll get combinatorial explosion of sales and expenditures, which will exaggerate your sums.

Why use `DATE(date)`?  Because that will allow the `date` columns in your detail tables to contain date/time values in case you want that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select l.dates,l.total_sale,
v.total_expenditure
from 

 (select l.dates dates,sum(total_sale)total_sale
 from ledger l 
 where l.dates between '2018-01-29' and '2018-01-31'
 group by l.dates)l

left join 

 (select v.dates,sum(expenditure)total_expenditure
  from voucher v 
  where v.dates between '2018-01-29' and '2018-01-31'
  group by v.dates)v

 on l.dates=v.dates;
```